# Is it possible to get the current transaction's transactionIndex from within a Solidity function call?

Tags: solidity, transactions, evm

Is it somehow possible to get the current transaction's index in the block from within Solidity? or to derive this in some indirect way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible since such opcode doesn't exist. There's no opcode that can identify a transaction within a block from the EVM side.